# Try block not working correctly

Tags: ios, swift, try-catch

I'm working on a app in which the api is called through NSURLSession. When the Api works correctly there is no problem but when no data is received due to any error then after Serialization it throws error but the else block for it is never called

```
 let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (let data, let response,  let error) in


        do {
            guard let data:NSData = data , let response: NSURLResponse = response where error == nil else {
                throw error!
            }

            guard let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? NSDictionary else{
                print("Serialization failed") //This block never executes even if the Serialization Fails
                throw JSONError.ConversionFailed

            }

            guard json.valueForKey("success") != nil else {
                return
            }


            self.apidata = json
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
            print(json.valueForKey("success")!)

        }
        catch let error as JSONError{
            self.showalertview(error.rawValue)
            print(error.rawValue)
        } catch let error as NSError{


            print(error.debugDescription)
        }
    }

    task.resume()
```

What I'm doing wrong here???

Comment: Which `else` block do you expect to run?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight i expect this to run when Serialisation fails
     else{
                print("Serialization failed") //This block never executes even if the Serialization Fails
                throw JSONError.ConversionFailed

            }

Comment: I suspect the third guard block is called when there is no data

Comment: Problem is the data is not is json format and therefore it's not gettting serialised so it should throw error from the second block. It's actually thowing error but the else block is not getting called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
do {
    guard let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? NSDictionary else {
        // A
    }
} catch {
    // B
}
```

If `NSJSONSerialization` throws an error (i.e. if it wasn't really a JSON response or if the response was malformed), it will proceed directly to `B` and the `guard` statement doesn't come into play. The `guard` statement will only execute `A` if and only if (a) the `NSJSONSerialization` call, itself, didn't throw any errors (i.e. the JSON was well-formed); but (b) the cast to the the dictionary failed (e.g. the top level JSON object was an array instead of a dictionary). That's an extremely unlikely scenario (your server would have to accidentally return a well formed JSON response that was not a dictionary, e.g. a JSON array).

---

To accomplish what you want, you would use `try?` to make sure that `NSJSONSerialization` wouldn't throw any errors, itself:

```
do {
    guard let json = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? NSDictionary else {
        // A
        throw JSONError.ConversionFailed 
    }
} catch {
    // B
}
```

By doing this, only if `A` performs a `throw` will `B` be called

Comment: Thanks for this. I really appreciate this help.